# Does the first_or_create method work for associations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm uploading records from a CSV file. But the file also has records with association data. **I need to ensure no duplicate data is saved because if the rake task runs multiple times.**

So, does `first_or_create` work with associations too?

Code is as follows:

```
   row = # FROM CSV Looping

    service_place = ServicePlace.first_or_create(
      name: row['NAME'],
      service_type: service_type,
      address_attributes:
      {
        line_1: row['LOCATION'],
        city: row['CITY'],
        province: row['PROVINCE'],
        postal_code: row['POSTAL_CODE'],
        latitude: coords[0],
        longitude: coords[1]
      }
    )
```

Comment: so why won't you just insert that sample data in your database, then try to call `first_or_create` and get an instant answer?

Comment: That obviously I did buddy. But was waiting for some cool suggestions/alternatives by some awesome people like you :)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to ensure no duplicate data is saved

Why not add a ActiveModel validation on your association, ensuring that the value should be unique? This way, you'll ensure that the data you'll have persisted will be unique.

Comment: It's not actual requirement that much. As admin has prevailage to create duplicate data if he want. But **don't want it to be created if a rake task is run 20 times for instance.**